# How to intercept the instantiated class name from the function?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, instance

I encountered an issue in one of my projects, I managed to reduce it to a simplest example possible. Consider the following

```py
class A:
    def f(self):
        return 'I am f()'

class B(A):
    def g(self):
        return 'I am g()'

a = A()
b = B()

print(a.f.__qualname__)
print(b.f.__qualname__)
print(b.g.__qualname__)
```

The output I am getting

```
A.f
A.f
B.g
```

the output I am expecting

```
A.f
B.f
B.g
```

because what I care about is not only the function name, but also the class name, not really the class in which the function is defined but rather the class that gets instantiated. Anyone has an idea how to get it?

Comment: Something like: `b.f.__self__.__class__.__name__ + '.' + b.f.__name__`?

Comment: Yes, just tried, that works! Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try something like:

```
def dynamic_qualname(method):
    return method.__self__.__class__.__name__ + '.' + method.__name__

print(dynamic_qualname(a.f))
print(dynamic_qualname(b.f))
print(dynamic_qualname(b.g))

# Output
A.f
B.f
B.g
```

Comment: Actually, I just found that that it works in the given example but if I apply `dynamic_qualname` to a function passed to a decorator I am getting `'function' object has no attribute '__self__'`

Comment: I found the reason why it was not working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467784/2398574 but your answer is perfectly fine for the question I provided. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the self attribute from f using the magic method **self** and access for the class and name, for example:

```
print(a.f.__self__.__class__.__name__)
```

So, your code will look like this:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        return 'I am f()'

class B(A):
    def g(self):
        return 'I am g()'

a = A()
b = B()

print(f"{a.f.__self__.__class__.__name__}.{a.f.__name__}")
print(f"{b.f.__self__.__class__.__name__}.{b.f.__name__}")
print(f"{b.g.__self__.__class__.__name__}.{b.g.__name__}")
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, perhaps the example I made is not exhaustive enough, if I apply your solution to function passed to a decorator I am getting `'function' object has no attribute '__self__'`

Comment: I edited the code, so I think will works now